# Schedulable State in Corda Event scheduling

Tags: kotlin, events, state, blockchain, corda

I was trying event scheduling feature by inheriting **schedulable states**, and I have tested the heartbeat example as well.

- Does a scheduling event happens only when a schedulable state is **newly issued** or it is **updated by consuming** ? Is it possible to do a recurring event using a same unconsumed state?
- When a schedulable state has two parties as participants, who will be actually initiating the scheduling flow mentioned in the  **nextScheduledActivity()**  function?
  (I know it happens automatically, but which party will be initiating
  that flow?)

Is it the same Party who issued the schedulable state is initiating the schedulable flow also?

Please help me to understand this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An activity is scheduled when a schedulable state is created and the activity is unscheduled if it gets consumed. So you can have one activity per state. You need to consume the state to schedule a new time. Take a look at this class, it is responsible for scheduling/ unschduling activities: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.7/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/events/ScheduledActivityObserver.kt
2. The activity will be triggered in all nodes who have the state recorded, you need to have a logic in your flow to restrict the flow from running in parties who should not run it. This should give you an idea: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flows/EndAuctionFlow.java

Answer (score 0):

Link to CordaLedger Slack Conversation:
https://cordaledger.slack.com/archives/C2KGD72UX/p1600771838039700